# Table doesn't exist error when used inside select statement and sub-query

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the error "Table 'metrics.t1' doesn't exist" even though t1 is defined. I've read several of the articles on here about doesn't exist errors and can't find a solution.

I can make it work if I replace "FROM t1 as t2" by inserting the entire t1 query into the from statement. However that means the huge t1 query runs twice, which takes about 4 minutes.

```sql
SELECT 
  date_format(t1.date, '%Y') as year, date_format(t1.date, '%m') as month, date_format(t1.date, '%d') as day, t1.epc, t1.scrap, t1.freight, t1.smo, t1.extsort, t1.total, 
  ( SELECT SUM(t2.total) / COUNT(t2.total)
    FROM 
   t1 as t2
    WHERE DATEDIFF(t1.date, t2.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 92
  ) AS movavg
FROM (SELECT date, sum(epc_labor_cost) as epc, sum(scrap_value) as scrap, sum(prem_freight_cost) as freight, sum(smo_sort_hours) as smo, sum(extsort) as extsort, sum(epc_labor_cost+scrap_value+prem_freight_cost+smo_sort_hours+extsort) as total FROM (
                                           select pn, date, labor_cost as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as extsort, 0 as total from epc_data 
                                 union all select pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, abs(value) as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as extsort, 0 as total from mke_scrap 
                                 union all select pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, cost as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as extsort, 0 as total from prem_freight 
                                 union all select pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, hours*4.02 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as extsort, 0 as total from smo_sort
                                union all select STRIP_NON_DIGIT(extsort.pn) as pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, (extsort.sorted*pn_data.extsort_cost) as extsort, 0 as total from extsort inner join pn_data on STRIP_NON_DIGIT(extsort.pn)=STRIP_NON_DIGIT(pn_data.pn) ) as test group by year(date), week(date,3) ORDER BY date desc) AS t1
ORDER BY t1.date desc limit 26
```

I'd like to be able to have it run the t1 query a single time for use in both parts of the full statement.

Comment: Format your code properly, then probably someone will help.

Comment: It's hard to read your query the way it is formatted, but you might want to consider rewriting the subquery. Instead of SUMing a UNION, you might want to consider UNIONing SUMs; by performing the union first, you end up adding a lot of 0s in those sums.

Comment: Uueerdo - I made updates to the code as you mentioned and it runs much faster. I hadn't thought of doing it that way, thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to find a way to join a subquery to itself, you may want to look into ***CTEs (Common Table Expressions***).

You cannot select from a subquery in the outer query's select; you can select fields from the subquery.

OK

```
SELECT t.something AS aSomething
FROM (SELECT * FROM x) AS t
;
```

NOT OK

```
SELECT (SELECT something FROM t LIMIT 1) AS aSomething
FROM (SELECT * FROM x) AS t
;
```

However, with CTEs you can do things like:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT * FROM x)
SELECT t1.*, SUM(t2.something)
FROM t AS t1 
INNER JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.somevalue > t2.somevalue
```

*I've mainly only used them in MSSQL, so my syntax for MySQL may be a little off.*

Comment: only if OP has mysql 8+

Comment: Correct, CTEs are relatively new to MySQL; if you're using an older version this is not an option, and the only way to do something similar is through some form of "temp" tables as discussed in user3115056's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a temp table first and then use the temp table for the querying. That way you are not query the same multiple times.

Comment: They cannot use a true TEMPORARY table for it though, MySQL does not allow referencing those kinds of tables more than once in a query; no self-joins, no unions, etc... They would need to temporarily create full tables, visible to all connections with possible issues involving multiple clients both making the attempt concurrently; it is doable, I've had to do it on many occasions, but usually you end up needing to dynamically generate those "temp" tables with a client identifier built into the name.

Comment: @Uueerdo: Ohk yes you are right... However how about using a procedure for the entire query? I am guessing this might be extensively used.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have table variables either. Another alternative is multiple copies of the temporary table.